# Get the size of public key using WinHttpQueryOption

Tags: c++, ssl-certificate, visual-c++-2010, winhttp

I need to find the **Public key** specified in certificate details. I have used WinHttpQuery option and provided WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT as the option flag.

```
bRet = WinHttpQueryOption(
hRequest,
WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT,
&pCert,
&dwLen
```

);

I found the public key encryption type using the structure returned from WinhttpQueryOption. Now I need to find the size of the public key

Example : RSA(2048 bits)

Is there a way to find the size of the public key using this method or is there any other way?

[Sample of certificate details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxTc8.jpg)

Comment: I think, `pCert` variable contains a pointer to a `CERT_CONTEXT` structure. You can go through this object (there is `pCertInfo` field which contains a pointer to a `CERT_INFO` structure). Use this to narrow down to `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`.

Comment: Yeah I did that and thats how I found the encryption algorithm. I can get the algorithm name and the public key (in encoded form). Now how do I get the size of the key?

Note : Public key is of CRYPT_BIT_BLOB type

Comment: The size of the public key is clearly stated as 256 bits. Don't post pictures of text here, and especially not links to pictures of text. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Umm, I posted it so that I can be clear in what I want from certificate details. Thats why I mentioned it as **Sample of certificate details** .

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching, I finally came up with the solution.

With WinHttpQueryOption, use WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT as the option flag and get the structure pCert(CERT_CONTEXT) . Now get the PCERT_INFO member of the structure to get details about the certificate. In PCERT_INFO use the **SubjectPublicKeyInfo** member, use the the function **CertGetPublicKeyLength()** and pass the SubjectPublicKeyInfo member as an argument to it. That function returns the length of the public key.

Code :

```
bRet = WinHttpQueryOption(
hRequest,
WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT,
&pCert,
&dwLen
);

cout<<"Alg Name : "<<pCert->pCertInfo-
>SubjectPublicKeyInfo.Algorithm.pszObjId<<endl;
CRYPT_BIT_BLOB pubKey = pCert->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey;

DWORD pLength = CertGetPublicKeyLength(X509_ASN_ENCODING | 
PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,&pCert->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo);
cout<<"Length of public key : "<<pLength<<endl;
```